# InvalidCastException, getting back ServiceStack.CompressedResult instead of data

Tags: c#, servicestack

Trying to call one servicestack service from inside another.

```
        using (var service = base.ResolveService<MyService>())
        {
            var vds = (List<MyData>)service.Any(params);
            foreach (var vd in vds)
            {
                DoStuff(vd);
            }
        }
```

Calling the service.Any(...) call generates the following exception:

Unable to cast object of type 'ServiceStack.CompressedResult' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DV.Svc.Model.MyData]'.

MyService does use the cache (return  base.Request.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you return:

```
base.Request.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(...)
```

You're returning the DTO on the first request to create the Cache, but then in subsequent requests it's returning the optimal cached version of the Services response (e.g. deflated JSON response).

You should refactor it so you can access the non-cached version of the Service, e.g:

```
using (var service = base.ResolveService<MyService>())
{
    var vds = service.GetMyData(params);
    foreach (var vd in vds)
    {
        DoStuff(vd);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can refactor the shared logic into a separate dependency so you don't need to communicate across Services. Both Services can then declare they want access to your dependency:

```
public IMyRepository MyRepository { get; set; }
```

Which can be used instead of calling the internal Service directly, e.g:

```
var vds = MyRepository.GetMyData(params);
foreach (var vd in vds)
{
    DoStuff(vd);
}
```